# get all data from an api and how to append only the title on a cell in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have my code below for pulling data from an api using alamofire. i did only pull the "title" . and append it. what i want is how do i get all of the data from the api including id , body and all but will only append the name on the cell i dont want all data to be shown. the details of the data will only show when You selected cell #(indexPath.item)! and its detail will be shown in an alert. i have my alert code below. for example i get all the data but i only show only the "titles" on the cell and when i click the cell it will show its data like when i click title which indexpath is 1 then it will show the id , body and all details of that title. Thank You.

```
alert

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(titleArray[indexPath.row])", message: "", preferredStyle:
                                    UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                let subview = (alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView

                                subview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 173/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0)

                                alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
                                    //                        let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
                                    //
                                    //                        if textField?.text != ""{
                                    //                            print("Text field: \(textField?.text!)")
                                    //                            self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)!)
                                    //                            self.setUpCollectionView()
                                    //                        }
//
//                                    item.isSelected = true
                                    print("oo")
                                }))
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

api sample

{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire



class MenuCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var titleArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBAction func signOutButtonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.showLoginScreen()
    }
    @IBOutlet var signoutButton: UIButton!
    var items = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.signoutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        demoApi()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton =  true

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArray.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func demoApi() {
        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")
                for item in json {

                    if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                        self.titleArray.append(title)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }

}


class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

**Step-1**

create the array of dictionary in your current class

```
var getAllDetail: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
```

**Step-2**

append your iterate dict to your new array of Dict named getAllDetail

```
 case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
            print("Response \(json)")
            for item in json {

                  getAllDetail.append(item)

               // if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                 //   self.titleArray.append(title)
               // }

            }
             if !getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                } 
            break
```

**Step-3**

finally append the value to your collectionview

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return getAllDetail.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
        cell.nameLabel.text = getTempDetails["title"] as? String  ?? "" //titleArray[indexPath.row]
          }
        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
           print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["userId"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
    }

    }
```

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]' at line  if let getTempDetails = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {

Comment: @DurnKurvirck- change this `if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row]`

Comment: i will implement It sir

Comment: Invalid redeclaration of 'getAllDetail'

Comment: oopss sorry my mistake

Comment: do you have skype  , so i can add you , and could repay you with a help also

Comment: if in case you need , i have a background in vue js , angular , backend node

Comment: maybe i could helo when ever you need

Comment: ive added you on skype

Comment: are you from chenai, tamil nadu?